# I have a django app in a ubuntu virtual machine and can't remotely access the postgres database

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu

I deployed an application in django on GCP in a VM (ubuntu 22.04 01 LTS)

The app is working normally, database is postgresql.

But I can't remotely access the database, I always get timeout error.

My **settings.py**

```
....
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ.get('DATABASE_ENGINE'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DATABASE_PORT'),
    }
}
...
```

My **.env** file :

```
# Postgres
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'django.db.backends.postgresql'
DATABASE_NAME = "basededados"
DATABASE_USER = "user"
DATABASE_PASSWORD = "senha"
DATABASE_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
DATABASE_PORT = "5432"
```

I created the database like this:

```
sudo -u postgres psql

CREATE ROLE user WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE PASSWORD 'senha';

CREATE DATABASE basededados WITH OWNER user;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE basededados TO user;
```

I already set up the **postgres.conf** file:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

And the **pg_hba.conf** file**:**

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

I alredy allowed port `5432` through the firewall by executing:

```
sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
```

I'm trying to access the DB like this:

```
psql -h {Virtual machine IP} -d basededados -U user
```

the error:

```
psql: error: connection to server at {Virtual machine IP}, port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

###### .env

```
# Postgres
DATABASE_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
DATABASE_NAME=basededados
DATABASE_USER=user
DATABASE_PASSWORD=senha
DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1
DATABASE_PORT=5432
```

Comment: I got a 502 error in the application with these changes

Comment: can you able to run the project through the port (ip) ?